# Is sex outdoor allowed in islam?

Tags: nikah, husband-wife, sexuality, intercourse

Dear anyone who can help me,
I want to know if certain outdoor practices are allowed with my wife

- sex in car but in empty location (eg-parking lot...) and fully covered
- sex in the backyard or beside the swimming pool area in a private villa or own house as walls are high and private
- creating a tent on an empty beach,land or desert with privacy and performing
- (indoor) having intimacy (at least like kiss and cuddle) whenever staying at (my or her) grand(family) house
  whenever family is staying but done behind locked doors.

thats all for now as i got a doubt about this topic, sorry for asking such question.

(BTW i **do not** need any **narration** and **inverse answers**, only direct with reasonable definition)
and can she wear frock in home or in my outdoor house premises?

jazakallah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is yes you can enjoy your wife outside, given you are careful and do it concealed. That is, no one can hear or see your activities in any way what so ever.
Allah (SWT) knows best.

Comment: jazakalla mate, how about wearing frock/summer wear on a daily basis in my house only with me?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. There's no awrah between you and your lady. So, you have nothing to worry about.